# Theory and vocabulary around ordering statements by "specificity"

Tags: logic, terminology

First, I apologize for not speaking the language of math well. I'm a computer programmer, but I'm asking here because I'm looking for possible areas of math that could help clarify my thinking on this topic.

This is a problem that's come up in different ways in software that I work on.

Say I have a set of objects, and I want to apply some rules to those objects. Let me make this somewhat concrete and say I'm talking about files. And I'm trying to assign to each file $f$ a certain property $P$, which for simplicity I'll say is a set of integers. I can't define each file's $P_f$ individually (too many files), so I make logical statements that select subsets of the files. Statements like:

1. Files under the directory D1 have $P_f$ containing {1,2}
2. Files under the directory D1/D2 have $P_f$ containing 3, but not 4.
3. Files that are images have $P_f$ containing 3
4. Files bigger than 10MB have $P_f$ not containing 3 and containing {4,5}.

Now trying to implement something like this program code becomes confusing, because, except for simple cases where operations are commutative, the order matters, so you have to think, what rules override or "come after" other rules. With statements 1 and 2 it's fairly obvious that a subdirectory is more "specific" than the outer directory. But with others, I guess it's kind of arbitrary?

How would do you describe this problem in terms used in mathematics? And is there any theory that could help clarify the concept of "specificity" here, or explain why there is no ordering of specificity and the rule application order has to be arbitrary and determined by the computer program.

(Not sure how to tag this, or if it's appropriate here.)

Comment: It isn't very clear what you want to implement. What are the inputs to your program and what are its outputs expected to be?

Comment: I thought that might be too off-topic to describe here, so I tried to make the question abstract. The same pattern has come up several times, but the most recent one is in a build system. So in that case I'm setting properties and compiler flags for files. But there are many rules for setting these properties and flags. For files in this directory, do A. For files with this extension, do B. When running in a certain mode, or for a certain architecture, do C. It's 1000's of lines of Python code. You could say the inputs are the rules, and the outputs are the compilation commands for each file.

Comment: I see. I suspect the mathematical formalism you need is either the [propositional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) or [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) calculus (depending on whether you have a fixed finite set of properties or properties that have parameters ranging over an unknown set (like file names)). But on a more implementation-oriented level, have you looked into how programs like "make" do this kind of thing?

Comment: You need to remove the arbitrariness. You are assigning various markers to objects. What is your purpose for assigning those markers? If the assignment of a particular marker can be arbitrary, why do you need that marker at all? I don't know what you are doing, but my thought would be to examine carefully what these markers are used for, and whether I couldn't come up with a set of markers to accomplish the purpose without being ambiguous.

Comment: I should clarify - the questions in my previous comment are questions I think you should be asking yourself, not questions I am asking you.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I've looked at some build systems, but so far haven't seen anything clearly explained, or in the code, that answers what I'm thinking about.

Comment: What happens with images bigger than 10MB?